# Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component when using useEffect hook

Tags: reactjs

i seem to be getting the following error when using `useEffect` hook.

> Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.

I believe it has something to do with the async function i am calling to set if the user is authenticated or not.

**ProtectedRoute.tsx**

```
export function ProtectedRoute({ ...routeProps }: ProtectedRouteProps): ReactElement | null {
    const context = useContext(AppContext);
    const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        isUserAuthenticated(context.token).then(setIsAuthenticated).catch(setIsAuthenticated);
    });

    if (isAuthenticated) {
        return <Route {...routeProps} />;
    } else {
        return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "login" }} />;
    }
}

const isUserAuthenticated = async (token: any): Promise<boolean> => {
    try {
        const response = await VerifyAuthentication(token);
        console.log("VerifyAuthentication", response);
        if (response.status !== 200) {
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    } catch (err) {
        return false;
    }
};
```

**App.tsx**

```
class App extends Component<Props, State> {
    renderRouter = () => {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <ProtectedRoute exact path="/" component={Dashboard} />
                    <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    };

    render(): ReactElement {
        return (
            <div className="App">
                <AppProvider>
                    <Theme>
                        <Sidebar>{this.renderRouter()}</Sidebar>
                    </Theme>
                </AppProvider>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably this redirects the user to a route which doesn't have this component:

```
return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "login" }} />;
```

Which means the component is unmounted, or generally unloaded from active use/memory.  And this *always* happens, because this condition will *never* be `true`:

```
if (isAuthenticated) {
```

Because when the component first renders that value is explicitly set to `false`:

```
const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
```

So basically what's happening is:

1. You fire off an asynchronous operation to check if the user is authenticated.
2. Before waiting for the response, you decide that the user is not authenticated and redirect them.
3. The component is unloaded because the user has left this page.
4. The asynchronous response is received and tries to update state for a component that is no longer loaded/mounted.

It's not entirely clear how this component is intended to fit into your overall structure, but you're going to need to change that structure.  Either checking for authentication would need to be synchronous or you'd need to wait for the asynchronous operation to complete before redirecting.  An example of the latter could be as simple as:

```
export function ProtectedRoute({ ...routeProps }: ProtectedRouteProps): ReactElement | null {
  const context = useContext(AppContext);
  const [isAuthenticated, setIsAuthenticated] = useState(false);
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(true);

  useEffect(() => {
    isUserAuthenticated(context.token)
      .then(x => {
        setIsAuthenticated(x);
        setIsLoading(false);
      })
      .catch(e => {
        setIsAuthenticated(false);
        setIsLoading(false);
        console.log(e);
      });
  });

  if (isLoading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>;
  } else if (isAuthenticated) {
    return <Route {...routeProps} />;
  } else {
    return <Redirect to={{ pathname: "login" }} />;
  }
}
```

In that scenario a separate state value of `isLoading` is used to track whether the asynchronous operation is still taking place, so the component "waits" until the data is loaded before deciding to redirect the user or not.

But overall I don't see why the authentication check can't be synchronous.  Something higher-level, such as a provider component that wraps the entire application structure within `<App/>`, can have this same logic above, essentially performing the async operation and keeping the result in state.  Then that state can be provided via `useContext` or Redux or even just passing as props to all child components.

You shouldn't need to re-check for authentication over and over in child components.  That's an application-level concern.

Comment: Very clear explanation thank you, this solved the problem so i have marked it as the solution.

Comment: However the console log i added in the isUserAuthenticated function fires 3 times when the page loads, which means its making 3 request whenever i refresh the page.

Comment: Whcih makes me think this is probably not the best place to have this authentication check and as you reccomended i should prob have the authentication check in in the appContext and hold a value  `isAuthenticated` in state and use this state value from the context instead

Comment: @Kay: How many instances of this component exist on the page?  It's just wrapping a `<Route/>`, so if it's wrapping more than one of them in your overall structure then it's unnecessarily repeating this operation.  The check for authentication should be at or very near the highest level of the component hierarchy, not wrapped around individual components.

Comment: I updated my OP where you can see where im using this function, it is used in App.tsx for handling protected routes.

Comment: @Kay: I would put this functionality above the `<Router/>` in the overall structure.  Mostly because you don't have much control over how the routing library mounts/unmounts things.  It should likely be close to the `<Theme/>` or some other global wrap-all component.  Put the authentication info in a context or in Redux or something like that.  Then the `<ProtectedRoute/>` component can just use that context instead of internally repeating the authentication check.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a variable to check component is mount or unmount when call `setIsAuthenticated`

```
useEffect(() => {
  let isMouted = true;
  isUserAuthenticated(context.token)
    .then((val) => isMouted && setIsAuthenticated(val))
    .catch(setIsAuthenticated);
  return () => {
    isMouted = false;
  };
});
```

Comment: This suppresses the error, but doesn't necessarily fix the problem.  The component will *always* unmount before the asynchronous operation completes.